# Progressive Web App Push Notifications Badge Not Masking

Tags: android, ios, progressive-web-apps

For my Progressive Web App push notifications, the badge logo I am using is not being masked and is just a square.

I've tried the logo as white and as black on a transparent background, and as black logo on white background

What format do you need to have the image to be automatically masked?

Comment: Should be a .png

Comment: I've done a .png with both a white background and a transparent background and both still don't get masked? @Mathias

Comment: Are you sure you have fully cleared out the browser cache of the device you are testing with? Perhaps have someone on a different device check to rule that out.